# Open Source software for 2D graphic animation like this:

Tags: animation, video, open-source

Can someone suggest me a good software of graphic 2D animation, for animating images, and also a software for insert some more or less static text during a video?
I'll post an example of my animation what should looks like, it start at 1:05 minutes in the video; while the text is for example the name of the people who are speaking :)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mmQl6VGvX-c

Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best 2D animation software](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/37775/best-2d-animation-software)

Comment: I'm searching for an opensource software

Comment: I bet you are not looking for *open source* but for *free* software instead. There is a huge difference. (Also, you get what you pay for.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Open source

- [NodeBox](https://www.nodebox.net/)
- Processing
- Your browser (serioulsy, you can do this with css and javascript easily)
- Blender (2d is just a subset of 3D)

## a NodeBox3 Example

A simple example of using NodeBox to make text appear, I had not used NodeBox 3 before so it took me 15-20 minutes to get up to speed (tough i have used shake and nuke  which are very similar). Its a good alternative if you abhor code, but still needs some polish.

[image: NodeBox animation]

**Image 1:** Simple example animation made with nodebox3.

[image: NodeBox graph]

**Image 2:** The NodeBox3 graph.

---

## Closed source (order of applicability)

- [Blackmagic Design: Fusion](https://www.blackmagicdesign.com/products/fusion) (download for free BUT not open source)
- Vvvv (free but not open source)

Comment: Just a note: Animation is a time consuming task. If one does animation even for a short time it usually pays back to have a good suitable tool at your disposal. The difference between the right tool and the adequate tool can literary be counted in days of work. In the long run this translates to hundreds if not thousands per month in lost revenue.