# Tools for creating high quality diagrams

Tags: images, software-recommendation, image-quality, diagram

I'm working on a technical paper in which there a lot of architecture diagrams, and I'm presently using pencil/dia tools to draw these images.

The problem with these images is, the text is not sharp in the final output (`png`). Can anyone suggest some tools for creating images of relatively higher quality?

**Edit**: My architecture diagrams contains elements used in flowchart.

Comment: Mostly a duplicate of [how to make wind flow aerodynamic diagrams](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/34994/how-to-make-wind-flow-aerodynamic-diagrams/34999#34999). Use illustrator. The core of the answer does not change much with your specification. If you do a lot of relationship graphs yEd is pretty nifty. But then again achitecture diagrams means many things to different people. Anyway if you can specify your needs a bit better you get better answers.

Comment: "the text is not sharp in the final output(png)" - maybe the problem is not the software you're using, but that the output is it at too low a resolution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest Illustrator. With its diagramm tools you can create any kind of diagram and its fully editable. Also you can output any kind of format in any resolution since its verctorbased graphics.

Of course, illustrator isn't free. If you don't want to invest money, maybe there's an alternative for you [here](http://www.onextrapixel.com/2011/03/15/10-best-alternatives-to-adobe-illustrator/).

I don't know whether those are suitable for you. If you *"draw"* your diagrams, also Photoshop can be useful.

I am not familiar with the *pencil/dia tool"* you are using, but might it be, that its not the software? Maybe you can change any kind of export options like quality, resolution or text-rendering? If you're using Photoshop, check what kind of text sharpening you got activated. For web (what i assume you're working for, since you export .png's) i'd recommend *"sharp"* mode. you find the option in the top option-bar.(sry my PS is german, but i guess it looks the same in english) [image]

Answer (score 3):

I know many people use https://www.lucidchart.com. If you are on Windows and have access to Visio, that is a good diagram tool as well.

Comment: Hi Jimmy! Welcome to GD.SE. Have you tried the tool, and if so, can you maybe add some more info about it in your answer so people know what sort of things you can do with it?